# Creating new instruction (double operand)

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, addressing-mode

I've been reading a book and i got stuck in this:

They showed me this chart:

[image]

I put this values by myself (does it make sense to you?):

> PC (program counter) = 16 bits
>
> TAR (temporary address register) = 16 bits
>
> MAR (memory address register) = 16 bits
>
> RTR = 8 bits Stack = 16 bits
>
> Index = 16 bits
>
> Page = 8 bits
>
> Aux1 = 8 bits
>
> Aux2 = 8 bits
>
> Accumulator A = 8 bits
>
> Accumulator B = 8 bits
>
> MBR = 8 bits
>
> Intruction register = 8 bits
>
> Address Bus = 16 bits
>
> Data Bus = 8 bits

I want to create my own intruction (**double operand**): Some of the addressing modes must use an internal CPU register (not limited to accumulators A and B only), for example page, index, stack.

i.e: A addressing mode where the index register contains the offset and the operand in the instruction indicates the address to add to that offset.

I was thinking about something like this:

> MOVE #$58, (INDEX) but it does not look correct to me

I'm quite lost right now :/...Could you please show me an example and briefly explain in what situation your mode of addressing would be useful?

Answer (score 0):

On x86 platform you can specify the base or index registers. E.g.
`mov ax, WORD PTR [bx] OR mov ax, [bx+si]`, here **bx** is base and **si** register content is index.

The instruction that you have mentioned seems to indicate that value INDEX will be added to base address in some **DEFAULT** register. If that is your intent than the instruction is okay. Otherwise there should be a provision for mentioning what the base register is, but only if there are many possible base registers.